# `spread= a - b` calculation on the tall data with `dplyr` and `data.table`

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have some (financial time-series) data in a tall format:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(Variable=c(rep("a",times = 3), rep("b", times=3)), 
                 Date=as.Date(c("2014-04-01","2014-04-02","2014-04-03"
                                ,"2014-04-02", "2014-04-03","2014-04-04")),
                 Value=c(1:3,3:1), key=c("Variable","Date"))
```

> DT

```
   Variable       Date Value
1:        a 2014-04-01     1
2:        a 2014-04-02     2
3:        a 2014-04-03     3
4:        b 2014-04-02     3
5:        b 2014-04-03     2
6:        b 2014-04-04     1
```

I would like to calculate a third variable `spread`, where `spread = a - b` for each common `Date` row (basically a spread between two time-series - a common transformation in the financial domain).

**Desired output:**

```
   Variable       Date Value
1:   spread 2014-04-02    -1
2:   spread 2014-04-03     1
```

I know of solution when I `dcast.data.table` the data into the wide format (i.e. into table with columns `c("Date", "a", "b")`), but due to performance issues on large data, is there an elegant way how to do this directly in the tall format using a)`dplyr` and b)`data.table` (two-part question)?

Ideally on the `dplyr` side, I am looking for something as expressive as `mutate(tbl_dt(DT, tall=TRUE), spread=a-b)`. *(Disclaimer: I am a complete newbie in `dplyr`)*

**Real-life dataset:**

```
# download 200 stocks from Quandl.com. requires free registration
library(Quandl); library(data.table); library(plyr)
ntickers <- 200 ; auth.token="register_free_to_obtain_token"
code.file <- tempfile()
download.file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/quandl-static-content/quandl-stock-code-list.csv",
              destfile=code.file)
tickers <- na.omit(read.csv2(code.file, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[,"Price.Code"])
lst <- na.omit(tickers)[1:ntickers]
names(lst) <- lst
Q <- ldply(lst, Quandl, 
           type = "raw", end_date="2014-04-08", 
           sort="asc", auth=auth.token) # might take minutes
DT <- as.data.table(Q)[,Date:=as.IDate(Date)]
setnames(DT, ".id", "Instrument")
setkey(DT, Instrument, Date)

> dim(DT); object.size(DT)
[1] 685512      8
41145752 bytes
> DT
              Instrument       Date Open High  Low Close Volume Adjusted Close
     1:    GOOG/AMEX_ABI 1981-03-11   NA   NA 6.56  6.75 217200             NA
     2:    GOOG/AMEX_ABI 1981-03-12   NA   NA 6.66  6.88 616400             NA
     3:    GOOG/AMEX_ABI 1981-03-13   NA   NA 6.81  6.84 462000             NA
     4:    GOOG/AMEX_ABI 1981-03-16   NA   NA 6.81  7.00 306400             NA
     5:    GOOG/AMEX_ABI 1981-03-17   NA   NA 6.88  6.88 925600             NA
    ---                                                                       
685508: YAHOO/TSX_AHX_TO 2014-04-02 0.75 0.75 0.75  0.75   5000           0.75
685509: YAHOO/TSX_AHX_TO 2014-04-03 0.79 0.82 0.75  0.82  25700           0.82
685510: YAHOO/TSX_AHX_TO 2014-04-04 0.81 0.81 0.78  0.80   4500           0.80
685511: YAHOO/TSX_AHX_TO 2014-04-07 0.80 1.05 0.80  0.96  40400           0.96
685512: YAHOO/TSX_AHX_TO 2014-04-08 0.95 0.96 0.90  0.95  21300           0.95
```

Comment: let's say 5mil rows * 3 cols (1000 instruments, each with 20 year daily history) Yes I know `dcast.data.table`, that's what I've had in mind. Question edited

Comment: can happen anywhere (data gaps, holidays etc.) Also, position of `a` and `b` within the date groups is not known in advance and there might be other variables as well, so this needs referencing/subsetting by variable name (`a - b`), not by position (`Value[1] - Value[2]`), apologies for not being clear

Comment: I can generate some typical big sample (multivariate price data), as this is quite recurring theme in finance. What's the common method of sharing multi-MB data on SO, link to Google Drive?

Comment: @Arun your deleted solution seems like the straightforward way to go (btw filtering NA's after might be cheaper than doing it during with that `if`) - why *is* it deleted?

Comment: @Arun included code for bigger dataset download

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ought to be able to work with this:

```
> merge(DT["a", ], DT["b",], by="Date")
         Date Variable.x Value.x Variable.y Value.y
1: 2014-04-02          a       2          b       3
2: 2014-04-03          a       3          b       2
```

The help page for `merge.data.table` suggests you read FAQ 1.12 for a detailed comparison of this with X[Y,...] approaches.

Comment: Thanks, solves the problem. +1 for a one-liner and the FAQ reference. One drawback of merge vs X[Y, ...] is that the former doesn't support `roll` argument. Even though I did not touch it in the original question, consider case with observation gaps when scientist tolerates replacing missing values using last available ones: `unique(setkey(rbind(X[Y, roll=T, rollends=FALSE], Y[X, roll=T, rollends=FALSE], use.names=T), Variable, Date))`. In this specific question, `X=DT["a",]; Y=DT["b",]`. Thanks for the FAQ 1.12 perspective!

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach with dplyr. First we create the data:

```
require(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  Variable = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 3), 
  Date = rep(as.Date("2014-04-01") + 0:2, 2),
  Value = c(1:3, 3:1)
)
```

Instead of rotating into a wide form, we could instead use a vectorised
comparison:

```
df %.% 
  group_by(Date) %.%
  summarise(spread = Value[Variable == "a"] - Value[Variable == "b"])

## Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
## 
##         Date spread
## 1 2014-04-01     -2
## 2 2014-04-02      0
## 3 2014-04-03      2
```

This will correctly fail if there are multiple values of a or b, because
`summarise()` requires that results are of length one. The same approach
would work with data.table, but you'd need to be a little more careful
about checking the results (because data table is less strict/more
flexible here compared to dplyr).

You could also use the join approach suggested by BondedDust. It's not
as quite as convenient with dplyr as it is with data.table:

```
a <- df %.% filter(Variable == "a") %.% select(-Variable)
b <- df %.% filter(Variable == "b") %.% select(-Variable)

inner_join(a, b, by = "Date") %.%
  mutate(spread = Value.x - Value.y)

##         Date Value.x Value.y spread
## 1 2014-04-01       1       3     -2
## 2 2014-04-02       2       2      0
## 3 2014-04-03       3       1      2
```

Comment: thanks for the introduction, I very much like the `df %.% group_by(Date) %.% summarise(spread = Value[Variable == "a"] - Value[Variable == "b"])` syntax. To further make it even more compact (perhaps at the risk of too many loose ends), do you think that `summarise` or `mutate` could directly accept a formulaic expression `spread = a - b` as an argument and parse it with the tall/wide format agnostic logic, so that if no columns are found with that names, guess them as row subsets (think of `reshape2:::guess_value` analogy).

Comment: @DanielKrizian no. I think you should store variables in a standard way and use a standard way of referring to them, a la http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html

Comment: thanks, I took time to read the document. Interesting framework. [Quite common case in financial modelling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966527/tidy-data-structure-ohlcv-financial-market-data)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a data.table method by using dcast.data.table.

I hope I provide an useful start, and there're some following issues about selecting NAs, and speed gain.

```
# Create Dataset
require(data.table)
require(reshape2)
DT <- data.table(Variable=c(rep("a",times = 3), rep("b", times=3)), 
             Date=as.Date(c("2014-04-01","2014-04-02","2014-04-03"
                            ,"2014-04-02", "2014-04-03","2014-04-04")),
             Value=c(1:3,3:1), key=c("Variable","Date"))

# using data.table
DT2 <- dcast.data.table(DT, Date ~ Variable, drop=FALSE) 
DT2[, spread:= a-b, by = Date][!is.na(spread),]
# Actually I'm not clear about the different between `drop= FALSE` and `drop = TRUE`
```

This is the output

```
         Date a b spread
1: 2014-04-02 2 3     -1
2: 2014-04-03 3 2      1
```

Comment: `drop=FALSE` also includes missing combinations. Consider `DT <- data.table(x=1:2, y=3:4, z=5:6, val=1L); dcast.data.table(DT, x+y~z, value.var="val", drop=TRUE)`. Now change `drop=FALSE` and try it again.